# CSS @import with URL / Path specified as a custom property (variable)

Tags: html, css

I was thinking about a convenient way to create and use themes in HTML / CSS / JS. One possible solution I was thinking of was specifying the path to the theme file as a variable and importing the theme file in the main stylesheet via said variable so something along these lines:

```
:root {
     --theme: url("default-theme.css");
}

@import var(--theme);
```

This way, if later the theme needs to be changed (for instance for Halloween or for the holiday season etc), the theme can be updated by either manually updating the value of the CSS variable or by using JS / TS to programmatically update the value.

I have tried a couple of different iterations of this including:

```
:root {
     --theme: "default-theme.css";
}

@import var(--theme);
```

and

```
:root {
     --theme: "default-theme.css";
}

@import url(var(--theme));
```

But sadly, nothing seems to work. I have also read through the documentation for CSS custom properties and CSS import and so far I have not really found anything.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-nwdujt?file=styles.css) is some editable sample code on StackBlitz. If anyone has any advice or suggestions or some wisdom to share, I will be extremely appreciative.

Comment: You can use `<link>` tag to the include the CSS theme file, and use JS to change the `href` of the `link` tag when you need to update the theme.

Comment: This would work but I am curious if there's a way this could be accomplished within the main css file.